# How to use a Dialog box inside a Card Action Button Group

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have a Dialog box as a button inside a Button Group, inside a CardActions component in Material UI.

When I use a regular Button instead of a Dialog, the 3 buttons in the CardActions are evenly justified across the width of the component - which is what I'm trying to preserve, whilst making the onClick action of the button, a pop up dialog box.

I have:

```
<CardActions>
                            <ButtonGroup
                                orientation="horizontal"
                                color="secondary"
                                aria-label="vertical contained primary button group"
                                variant="text"
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                <1 /> 
                                <2 />
                                <3 Services</Button>
                            </ButtonGroup>
                        </CardActions>
```

Each of 1, 2 and 3 are files which have:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import LaunchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Launch';

export default function ScrollDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState('paper');

  const handleClickOpen = (scrollType) => () => {
    setOpen(true);
    setScroll(scrollType);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const descriptionElementRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      const { current: descriptionElement } = descriptionElementRef;
      if (descriptionElement !== null) {
        descriptionElement.focus();
      }
    }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button  color="secondary"  onClick={handleClickOpen('paper')}>
        1
      </Button>
      
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        scroll={scroll}
        aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
        maxWidth="sm"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Sampling Techniques</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers={scroll === 'paper'}>
          <DialogContentText
            id="scroll-dialog-description"
            ref={descriptionElementRef}
            tabIndex={-1}
          >
           
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          
          
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try this, the Dialog pops up like a modal, but the buttons do not preserve the justification styling of the ButtonGroup (that worked when I just used buttons inside that Card Action component).

Is it possible to have a Dialog box inside a Card Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.MuiButtonGroup-root` is an `inline-flex` container. Use `width: "100%"` and `justifyContent: "space-evenly"` so that

> the 3 buttons in the CardActions are evenly justified across the width
> of the component

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customBtnGroup: {
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  }
});

<ButtonGroup classes={{ root: classes.customBtnGroup }}>
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]